# Deserialization throws an exception for this bit of C# code

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, memorystream

I have some binary data I've read in. I wish to convert it to an `System.Drawing.Image`, so I create an instance of an `Image object`, using a `memory stream` as the input data.

After I've done that, I serialize then deserialize the image (for some business logic). The deserialize throws an exception. If I create the `Image` instance with the file name constructor instead of the memory stream constructor, it all works 100%. This suggests that the `Image` object can be serialized over the wire.

What am I doing wrong with `memory stream`, I've used?

This is the code I use to make the Image object, before it gets serialized:

```
// Fake way of getting some binary (image) data.
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("Chick.jpg");

using (Stream originalBinaryDataStream = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    // This works perfectly fine, if use this method (which i can't).
    //image = new Bitmap("Chick.jpg");

    // This throws an exception when it's deserialized.
    // It doesn't like the memory stream reference?
    image = new Bitmap(originalBinaryDataStream);     
}
```

This is the code that tries to deserialize the image, which throws an exception ([this is a separate image of the exception](https://img254.imageshack.us/img254/9748/step1zx3wk5.png))

[image]

Is there something that is not correctly disposed off OR cannot be serialised, hence throwing the exception?

### Edit

The exception is called in my *Image Debugger Visualizer*.

I've uploaded the complete VS2008 solution [here](http://drop.io/lssibqa) (1.28MB download).

In it are two projects -> the **visualizer class** and the **MS Test class**. If u run the only unit test, it will throw the generic (read: useless) GDI+ exception as it fails to deserialize the Image instance that was passed across the wire to the debugger viz. If you passed it an Image instance that was created using the file path constructor, the deserialization works perfectly.

EDIT 2: used a different file upload site.

EDIT 3: How to actually reproduce the error.

- Change project to DEBUG mode (not release mode)
- Remove all break points.
- Open up ImageDebuggerVisualizer.cs
- Add a breakpoint to line 22.
- Now *debug* the UnitTest1 unit test method. An image will show .. close that window .. then suddenly you will be on the break point. Step over that and it crashes.

EDIT 4: Here are two SCREEN SHOTS of the exception (if you don't want to download the solution file).

- [Before I step over the offending line](https://img254.imageshack.us/img254/9748/step1zx3wk5.png)
- [After I step over the offending line](https://img383.imageshack.us/img383/1677/step2uj0.png), where the exception is thrown.

### Edit 5

Closing this because I've found the reason why it's erroring, but instead of removing this post, I generate a newer post with a more refined question.

Comment: We need the entire context of the code and the exception thrown.

Comment: What a terrible sharing site ! A tip for the future use http://drop.io/

Comment: nod Kees! i've changed it to your suggestion. cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that in your real code you are writing to a `MemoryStream` and not rewinding it; if this is the case, set Position to 0 before you try to re-load it.

Comment: He does not write to the memory stream, he initializes it with a byte array. No reposition required.

Comment: @Ovidiu - hence my mention of "real code"....

Comment: I added a seek to end on the memory stream and it still works, see my answer.

Comment: We need the entire context of the code and the exception thrown.

Comment: I've added the entire exception info in a screenshot (cause it's a massive exception) to the opening post.

Answer (score 2):

Just tested your code, it worked, the code is fine. There must be a problem with the image file or path.
This is my test:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     
       {
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\t.jpg");

            using (Stream originalBinaryDataStream = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                // This works perfectly fine, if use this method (which i can't).
                //image = new Bitmap("Chick.jpg");


                // This throws an exception when it's deserialized.
                // It doesn't like the memory stream reference?
                originalBinaryDataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                pictureBox1.Image=  new Bitmap(originalBinaryDataStream);
            }
        }
```

And I see the image in the PictureBox.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the initial question post with a link the entire VS solution (which is one class and one unit test). The unit test throws the fail fail fail exception. Please check it out.

Comment: No repro either, the unit test worked fine.  You'll have to post the stack trace of the exception.  At least the chick was worth it.

Comment: Hmm. i just dl'd the solution and repo'd the exception. I've added the steps to repo it, up in the original post. Please check out how it's repo'd. pwease?

Comment: You should post the exception thrown, as suggested earlier.

Comment: Added links in the original post that show the exception.